# Como extrair as informações do arquivo retorno do Itau em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, boleto

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual está sendo usado a biblioteca BoletoNet para gerar boletos. Nesse caso a própria biblioteca ao gerar os boletos gera também o arquivo remessa que precisa ser enviado para o banco.

Por outro lado, há também o arquivo retorno, que o banco fornece com o retorno referente as operações. Eu preciso processar esse arquivo e extrair as informações para salvar no banco de dados do programa para ficar disponível para o usuário ver.

O problema é que eu não encontro muita informação sobre esse arquivo e sobre como esse arquivo pode ser processado. Até achei um PDF do Itau sobre isso, mas não consegui entender como isso pode ser processado em C#.

Se fosse um XML, um CSV, um JSON, tudo bem. Mas parece que é só um TXT. Eu realmente não faço a menor ideia de como as informações são extraidas dele.

Parece que a BoletoNet possui uma API para isso, mas sinceramente essa biblioteca é *muito* mal documentada e eu não consegui descobrir ainda como pode ser usada nesse caso.

Nesse caso, considerando que seja dado um arquivo retorno do Banco Itau, como que ele pode ser processado em C# e ter as informações extraidas dele?

Answer (score 1):

Os arquivos de remessa e retorno que os bancos utilizam é padronizado pela FEBRABAN e são arquivos de texto simples, onde na documentação de cada banco tem o layout do arquivo.

O layout do arquivo é basicamente informações dizendo quais campos existem, em que posição começa, em que posição termina e qual o tipo do dado.

Por exemplo, temos a seguinte informação na documentação do Itau:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso quer dizer que no arquivo de remessa, o campo Código do Banco começa na posição 1 e termina na posição 3, o picture diz que é númerico com 3 posições e o conteúdo diz que neste caso tem que ser 341.

E assim por diante você vai fazendo para cada campo da documentação.